# Migrate a digital ID from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, encryption, certificate, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Our company has been issued circa 2012-2014 some confidential PDF documents that are locked with a "digital ID" (also called certificates, perhaps improperly). AFAIK only Adobe software knows how to decipher these documents when opened. **That still works fine on the Windows XP machine that originally was used to view these documents**. The doc opens normally (no password is asked) with Adobe Acrobat Reader XI under that XP machine, now virtualized. But when that's attempted on a modern machine without the digital ID installed, I get

> A digital ID was used to encrypt this document but no digital ID is present to decrypt it

Even though I have a working method to view the documents on a modern machine thru virtualization, I'd want to extract the "digital IDs" on that machine and bring them to a modern one.

I used the [MMC snap-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in) to view user certificates, found one, migrated it, and that solved the issue for a batch of documents issued 2014. But I could not find the "digital ID" for earlier documents. I think there is a certificate attribute to make it (conventionally) un-exportable, but my issue is I can't even find it.

Where/how should I look?

---

Update: Thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732895/221661) and some dichotomy, I found that the three files `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Adobe\Acrobat\11.0\Security\lb.dat`, `lbi.dat`, and `lbk.dat` (and no other file in that folder) are instrumental in the ability to open the documents that depend on the certificate that I'm trying to find. When one is removed, Acrobat Reader 11.0.23 prompts me with with a "Digital ID Authentication" dialog, showing the characteristics of the certificate necessary to open the document, when I dismiss that, I get the error message at the begining of that answer. When I open the same doc in a fresh install of Acrobat Reader 11.0.23 in another machine, I get the error message directly. And transporting the `lb*.dat` files does not cut it.

I tentatively conclude the certificate is somewhere else, and the `lb*.dat` contain some enabler/key rather than the certificate itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/transferring-digital-signatures-between-laptops/m-p/11834105#M298179) Digital ID's exist as file on your disk so you can try to find them, transfer to new machine, import and check if they work. Here is important part from the answer:

> If you originally created the signature as a  PKCS#12 file, then it
> should be easy to find that `.pfx` file in this location on Windows:
> `Local Disk>Users>username>AppData>Roaming>Adobe>Acrobat>DC>Security`
> Once that file is transferred, then use the Add ID function

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a single *.pfx file on the whole XP machine, including `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Adobe\Acrobat\11.0\Security`which sorta matches, but only has 6 .dat files and a .acrodata file. I searched for *.p12 files, found one which from the name and date must be what I'm missing, _but_ it's password protected and I have lost the password. I'm convinced this was imported in the XP install by double clicking and using the wizard (not thru Acrobat), so it's stored where certificates are stored, I only I can't find it!

Comment: @fgrieu, have you check all the installed certificates (as administrator)? Maybe this one is installed in odd area?

Comment: I tried my best, but can't find that certificate (only a different one, that I can extract and migrate). I wonder what "as administrator" means under XP, and did not do anything in that direction. I'm logged as a user with admin privilege (and the only user in C:\Documents and Settings beside All Users).

Comment: @fgrieu, did you browse all the tabs on this screen? https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/WindowsXProotcert/trustedCert.bmp

Comment: @fgrieu, you can check also this manual if you found a certificate: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/copy-certificate-from-one-pc-to-another-xp-pro-to/ffc404f4-87cc-4bb6-870e-32aea785dbaf

Comment: Thanks, had not used "Internet properties/Content/Certificate" before. It shows the certificate I already know, and (in a second tab) a certificate I did not knew. It's in the name of the publisher of the PDF (when the other certificate is in my name), and when I try to export it, I'm not given the option to export the private key. Also the issue date is months earlier than I expect the missing certificate to be. Thus I'm leaning towards thinking that's just a public key certificate for the publisher, rather than the certificate with private key that I'm looking for (I'm sure it is there !)

Comment: ***Update*** I tried to remove all Adobe folders I could find in `C:\Documents and Settings\user\` . After that I can still open some documents that require the certificate I know, but no longer the ones requiring the certificate I'm looking for. Thus it lives in Adobe as you suggested in the answer! I'll find where by dichotomy (VMs are wonderful). I'll make an answer when I get the hang of it!